# Which are the shortest and longest mantras from Vedas

Tags: vedas, mantras

There are many mantras in Vedas. Among them, which one is the shortest mantra and which one is the largest mantra in terms of length?

Is it om, the shortest mantra?

Note that the length of mantra I am referring to is the no.of Sanskrit characters in the mantra. For example ब्रह्म has length 2. सरस्वति has length 4 etc.,

Comment: Second question can be which one is the longest mantra from Vedas?

Comment: @Paṇḍyā Yeah...

Comment: Shortest in what sense? Uchcharan or meter?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I mean, no.of Sanskrit letters in the mantra...

Comment: @hanugm Oh! In that case, i don't see it meaningful/quality question.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I just wanted to know about the measurable attributes of Vedic mantras like length. The issue is that I like mantras so much, but not eligible to recite, it may be the reason for my interest towards other aspects...

Comment: a 'word' in Sanskrit is a mantra....

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda is it true that any word in Sanskrit can be a mantra?

Comment: Probably the shortest mantra in the Vedic literature is in Atharva veda. This sukta is  just of  single line giving the names of the chief Vedic metres also known as Chandansi sukta (छन्दासि सूक्त ) Atharva-Veda Book 19-Sukta 21. https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av19021.htm and http://literature.awgp.org/book/atharveda/v5.87  just 25 letters.

Comment: We can see the long mantras in  main Upanishads.

Answer (score 3):

## Short  letter Mantras

Probably the shortest sukta in the Vedic literature is in [**Atharva veda**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av19021.htm). This sukta is  just of  single line giving the names of the chief Vedic metres also known as Chandansi sukta (छन्दासि सूक्त ) Atharva-Veda Book 19-Sukta 21.This mantra is **just having 25 letters** splitting the words in multiple letters.

> गायत्र्यु १ष्णिगनुष्टुब् बृहती पंक्तिस्त्रिष्टुब् जगत्यै ||1||
>
> Gāyatri, Ushnih, Anushtup, Brihatī, Trishtup, Jagatī.

[**AWGP Link**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/atharveda/v5.87)

---

## The long letter mantras.

The longest letter mantras in Vedic texts are mostly found in Main Upanishads like Prashna Upanishad.
Also, probably longest letter mantra in my brief search I have come across is from same  [**Prashna Upanishad 4.8**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/prashna-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145327.htmls) having **close to 200 letters** splitting the words in multiple letters.

> पृथिवी च पृथिवीमात्रा चापश्चापोमात्रा च तेजश्च तेजोमात्रा च वायुश्च
>   वायुमात्रा चाकाशश्चाकाशमात्रा च चक्षुश्च द्रष्टव्यं
>  च श्रोत्रं च
>   श्रोतव्यं च घ्राणं च घ्रातव्यं च रसश्च रसयितव्यं च त्वक्च
>   स्पर्शयितव्यं च वाक्च वक्तव्यं च हस्तौ
>  चादातव्यं
>   चोपस्थश्चानन्दयितव्यं च पायुश्च विसर्जयितव्यं च यादौ च गन्तव्यं च
>   मनश्च मन्तव्यं च बुद्धिश्च बोद्धव्यं
>  चाहङ्कारश्चाहङ्कर्तव्यं च
>   चित्तं च चेतयितव्यं च तेजश्च विद्योतयितव्यं च प्राणश्च विधारयितव्यं च
>   ॥ 4.8॥
>
> Earth and its subtle form, water and its subtle form, fire and its subtle form, air and its subtle form, âkâsa and its subtle form, sight
>   and its objects, taste and its objects, touch and its objects, speech
>   and object, hands and what is to be handled, the organ of generation
>   and what is to be enjoyed, the organ of excretion and what must be
>   excreted, the feet and what is to be trodden on by them, mind and what
>   must be thought, the intellect and what must be determined, egotism
>   and its object, Chitta and its object, light and its object, and Prâna
>   and what must be supported by it.

However, it is possible that such mantras are also present in the Samhita part and in other Upanishads also.